# C++ define changeable macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible in C++ to create variable, which will be expanded after each time it used to different value?

For example, I want that following

```
#define mytype [smth here]
void foo(mytype a,mytype b,mytype c)
```

will be expanded into

```
void foo(mytype1 a,mytype2 b,mytype3 c)
```

or

```
void foo(mytype1 a,mytype11 b,mytype111 c)
```

Comment: short answer No; long answer: Nooooooooo

Comment: Macros are expanded during preprocessing.  You can't.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @devnull But here I need that they expand during preprocessing.

Comment: `#define myvar myvar1` replace myvar to myvar1. if the macro is part of the word it do nothing, only the whole word is count. try to describe what you want to do.

Comment: It wouldn't be as simple as using a macro, but you could achieve something like that with [Boost.Preprocessor slots](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/evaluated_slots.html). Or perhaps use `__LINE__` in your macro's expansion.

Comment: From your question, it's clear you don't really mind how it changes: you're happy with `myvar11` or with `myvar2`.  Therefore you could use `__LINE__` as @Angew said.  But it might be better to just be honest about what your real problem is.

Comment: __ LINE __ doesn't suits. Something like     __ COLUMN __ will be good

Comment: Do you really have to declare multiple variables on one line?

Comment: @user2992539: Speaking as someone who has been working on other people's C++ for a living for the last 12 years: Don't do this. It simplifies **nothing**, and no experienced C++ coder will welcome such macro magic. Please post another question describing what your template should do, and let us figure out how to do that efficiently **and** elegantly, *without* doing fancy macros. You might be surprised, you might learn something, and we'll be fixing the *cause*, not the *symptoms*. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to achieve the function parameter thing:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum_binary_params.hpp>

void foo(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS(3, mytype, p));
```

That will expand to

```
void foo(mytype0 p0, mytype1 p1, mytype2 p2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a macro that changes what it expands to, but you can make what it expands to mean different things:

```
std::string foo()
{
    static int x;
    return std::string("myvar") + std::to_string(x++) + "\n";
}

#define myvar foo()
```

and

```
cout<<myvar;
cout<<myvar;
```

will print out

```
myvar1
myvar2
```

Comment: foo() will be expanded during running time, but I need so during compile time(

Comment: @user2992539 what for?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I wanted to use such macros in function declaration as types

Comment: So void foo(poo a,poo b); become void foo(poo1 a,poo2 b);

Comment: @user2992539 you can use templates for that.

Comment: there should be achievements for this kind of stuff :)

Comment: It was planned to be used in template declaration to simplify things.

Comment: @user2992539 you and I have different definitions of the word simplify. Sure, you save about 1 second of typing (in total), but the loss of readability is far **FAR** worse.

Comment: I was going to write header with some template functions and this will simplify things for header's user.

Comment: @user2992539 this, if it did work, will not simplify anything. It's bad for both the user and the developer.

Answer (score 0):

If it should only increase when outputting, you can define a struct overriding the `operator<<`, e.g.:

```
struct myvarstruct {
  int i;
  myvarstruct() : i(1){}
} myvar;

ostream &operator << (ostream &o, myvarstruct &s) {
  return o << "myvar" << s.i++;
}
```

Comment: I need it increase during preprocessing/compilation, not running time.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define mytype [smth here]
#define TYPE(a, b) _TYPE(a, b)
#define _TYPE(a, b) a##b
void foo(TYPE(mytype, 1) a, TYPE(mytype, 2) b, TYPE(mytype, 3) c)
```